# I am using lookup in mongodb aggregation, but it doesnt return data i am looking for

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Here is a sample building collection.

```
{
    _id: 5e4aa096a6b7db2270c65815,
    previous_audit: false,
    no_of_people: 3,
    project_name: 'UNDP',
    premise_contact: 'Kanagaraj',
    premise_address: 'Delhi',
    premise_city: 'Delhi',
    premise_state: 'Delhi',
    premise_country: 'IN',
    latitude: '28.593716',
    longitude: '77.222391',
    building_name: 'Nemi',
    building_type: 'Hospital',
    climate_zone: 'Hot & Dry',
    no_of_stories: '3',
    year_of_occupation: 3,
    gross_area: 3333,
    gross_area_units: 'Square Meters',
    lease_type: 'Annual Rental',
    campus_id: 5e4857816560b92a58129e68,
    project_name_lower: 'undp',
    createdAt: 2020-02-17T14:17:58.892Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-02-17T14:17:58.892Z,
    __v: 0,
}
```

And in first pipeline stage i am using $match function.

```
Building.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            campus_id: {
                $in: campus_ids
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'manual_meters',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'building_name',
            as: 'manual_meter'
        }
    }
])
```

But when looking lookup , it always return empty arryay in manual_meter.
This is the respnse i am getting. ALthough the collection manual meter contains the id of building, but still it doesnt return the manual meter collection.

```
 {
    _id: 5e4857816560b92a58129e72,
    previous_audit: false,
    project_name: 'UNDP',
    premise_contact: 'Kanagaraj',
    premise_address: 'Delhi',
    premise_city: 'Delhi',
    premise_state: 'Delhi',
    premise_country: 'IN',
    latitude: '28.593716',
    longitude: '77.222391',
    building_name: 'U.N.House',
    building_type: 'Office',
    climate_zone: 'Hot & Dry',
    no_of_stories: '4',
    year_of_occupation: 1970,
    gross_area: 6500,
    gross_area_units: 'Square Meters',
    lease_type: 'Owned',
    campus_id: 5e4857816560b92a58129e68,
    project_name_lower: 'undp',
    createdAt: 2020-02-15T20:41:37.171Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-02-15T20:41:37.171Z,
    __v: 0,
    manual_meter: []
  },
  {
    _id: 5e4aa096a6b7db2270c65815,
    previous_audit: false,
    no_of_people: 3,
    project_name: 'UNDP',
    premise_contact: 'Kanagaraj',
    premise_address: 'Delhi',
    premise_city: 'Delhi',
    premise_state: 'Delhi',
    premise_country: 'IN',
    latitude: '28.593716',
    longitude: '77.222391',
    building_name: 'Nemi',
    building_type: 'Hospital',
    climate_zone: 'Hot & Dry',
    no_of_stories: '3',
    year_of_occupation: 3,
    gross_area: 3333,
    gross_area_units: 'Square Meters',
    lease_type: 'Annual Rental',
    campus_id: 5e4857816560b92a58129e68,
    project_name_lower: 'undp',
    createdAt: 2020-02-17T14:17:58.892Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-02-17T14:17:58.892Z,
    __v: 0,
    manual_meter: []
  }
]
```

Below is a sample manual_meter collection.

```
    {"_id":"5e4ad8e1a3833e2bb44b4dcb",
"meter_data : [],
"meter_name":"undp_unh",
"meter_id":"1001",
"meter_type":"energy",
"campus_name":"UNDP",
"building_name":"5e4857816560b92a58129e72",
"floor_name":"common",
"zone_name":"common",
"createdAt":"2020-02-17T18:18:09.192Z",
"updatedAt":"2020-02-17T18:18:09.192Z",
"__v":0}
```

Comment: Can you show the document you're trying to match from `manual_meter` collection? What is the data type for `_id` and for `building_name`?

Comment: @mickl _id is object id type and building_name contains object id but in string format

Comment: It is working. Check this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mNH1QWyGh6V). I guess you test with bad data, so it doesn't lookup correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to match `string` against `ObjectId` which won't work, even if the values are the same. You can run [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) on your `_id` field as part of [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries):

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "manual_meters",
        let: { building_id: { $toString: "$_id" } },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match:{
                    $expr: {
                        $eq: [ "$$building_id", "$building_name" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        as: "manual_meter"
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks.
It helped a lot